# How can I create an AD user via PowerShell prompting for options?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a PowerShell script which will create users based on template users I've created. The initial steps I'm trying to figure out are below:

- Upon execution of the script show a prompt asking for the employee's name
- Next show a prompt asking what department the user will work for (the departments should be linked to the template AD users to copy their group memberships)
- Next ask their location which will automatically add some group memberships

Can somebody please point me in the right direction of how I would go about getting started with this script?

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Well, to prompt for user input you want to use the `Read-Host` cmdlet, such as

```
$name = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter your name'
```

The most up to date information can be found on Microsoft's website for the cmdlet. I hope this points you in the right direction.

Beware, this is not suitable for password prompts!

Answer (score 0):

[This TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617195.aspx) and its children give you a very broad range of cmdlets related to Active Directory, most of which are very intuitively named. You'll probably be interested in ones such as:

- [New-ADUser](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617253.aspx)
- [Add-ADGroupMember](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617210.aspx)
- [Add-ADPrincipalGroupMember](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617203.aspx)

As mentioned in Answer #1, [Read-Host](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849945.aspx) will let you prompt for input.

In order to process a number of different options for location as per the third bullet point in your question, you may use a switch statement.

```
$Location = Read-Host "Enter user's location"
Switch ($Location) {
   "First Floor" { } #Add code to add user to First Floor Groups
   "Second Floor" { }
}
```

One issue you may run into here is that there is a very wide range of what the users of this script could potentially enter for the location, such as "First Floor" versus "first floor" versus "1st floor." As such, you may want to up the ante a bit and use `System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription` for this task instead of `Read-Host`. Take a look at [this TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730939.aspx) for more information.